# Writing each key in a default dict to a unique csv file

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict that has ID numbers as the keys to lists of coordinates, and I want to write it to a folder that has a unique csv file for each key.

So far this is what I have:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Simplified_Coordinates.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1.csv')

from collections import defaultdict

CoordDict = defaultdict(list)
for i in range (1,24134,1):
   coordinate_list=[(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value,   sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value)]
   for oID, yx in coordinate_list:
       CoordDict[oID].append(yx)

import csv

w=csv.writer(open('outputcoords.csv','w'))
for oID, yx in CoordDict.items():
   w.writerow([oID,yx])
```

But this writes all of the lists in the defaultdict to 1 csv with a separate line for each key. Any suggestions on the best way to write them each to their own csv file? Do I need another for statement? I'm very new to python sorry if this is an obvious question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want each of your coordinate lists written to a separate file, you can but the writing of the csv files into the `for` loop:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Simplified_Coordinates.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1.csv')

from collections import defaultdict
import csv

for i in range (1,24134,1):
    coordinate_list=[(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value,   sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value)]

    w=csv.writer(open('outputcoords%d.csv' % i,'w'))
    or oID, yx in coordinate_list:
       w.writerow([oID,yx])
```